# Have I finally gone insane, or does the "sign up" page of BitMitigate redirect to 127.0.0.1?

Tags: browser, web

I heard this mentioned today, so I looked it up: https://bitmitigate.com/

OK. Yet another ultra-confusing, nonsensical (to me) website with extremely unclear purpose. But once I clicked the big button saying "Get Started", which links to:

```
https://bitmitigate.com/user-panel/sign-up.html
```

... my browser (Pale Moon) actually went to:

```
http://127.0.0.1/
```

What could possibly explain this? I also tried with uBlock Origin turned off. Same result.

Comment: Both "Get Started" and "Sign Up" links are redirected to 127.0.0.1
A nasty way to avoid new customers.

Answer (score 7):

> does the “sign up” page of BitMitigate redirect to `127.0.0.1`?

Yes. `curl 'https://bitmitigate.com/user-panel/sign-up.html'` returns:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://127.0.0.1/">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>
```

`curl -L …` would redo the request on the new place, i.e. on `http://127.0.0.1/`. This is what most tools (including your browser) do automatically.